# Cannot get the value from database in PHP

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

I'm trying to get a value from database using the following code

```
    $request = Registrationrequest::where('course_id', $id)
                                   ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                                   ->where('registered', true)->count();
```

I'm using Laravel. I have a row with `course_id = 4`, `user_id=3` and `registered=true`. 
When I var_dump each values separately, I'm confirming it. But when I use this where condition together, I'm not getting the count value as 1, instead getting 0.

I have another query where I use

```
$request = Registrationrequest::where('course_id', $id)
                                ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                                ->where('registered', false)->first();
```

This works perfect when the registered value is false.

Can anybody tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: What is the `registered` column's type (in the database)?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen It's Binary

Comment: Does it work if you set it to `1` instead of `true`, and `0` instead of `false`?

Comment: No, it's not working. I tried that.

Comment: I found the problem. When I save the data, I saved registered as 'true' or 'false'. It has to be 1 or 0. When I changed all the false and true through out the code with 0 and 1, it worked.

Comment: Yeah. Laravel's model probably casts the boolean values to strings, which means that `true` becomes `'1'` and `false` becomes `''` (empty string). That probably causes problems somewhere.

Comment: You can submit this as an answer if you want. I'll mark it as completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `true` with `1`, and `false` with `0`.

Comment: Normally true and false should work. True is working. But not false case. Anyway, changing it to 1 and 0 works.

Comment: It is because they are being cast to string. When boolean values are cast to string they are turned into: `true` = `'1'` and `false` = `''` (empty string).

Answer (score 0):

Changed all the `false` and `true` from the `insert`, `delete` and `select` queries.

```
$request = Registrationrequest::where('course_id', $id)
                                ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                                ->where('registered', 0)->first();
```